# Redux Toolkit 1.9.3 and 'Property 'push' does not exist on type 'WritableDraft<CartState>'

Tags: typescript, redux, toolkit

Trying out ReduxToolkit with TypeScript and I'm stumped on something that I suspect is really simple / obvious. However, I don't know enough to figure it out and need some guidance.

Basically I get a **Property 'push' does not exist on type 'WritableDraft'.** error in the following code:

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { Product } from '../pages/Product/Types'

export interface CartState {
  products: Product[]
}

const initialState: CartState = {
  products: []
}

export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToCart: (state, action: PayloadAction<Product>) => {
      state.push(action.payload) <=== ERROR HERE, WITH 'push'
    }
  }
})

// Action creators are generated for each case reducer function
// export const { addToCart, decrement, incrementByAmount } = cartSlice.actions
export const { addToCart } = cartSlice.actions

export default cartSlice.reducer
```

I understand that push() isn't working because state isn't considered an array, but I don't see how to fix that, given what code is already here. Any help is appreciated; thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cart state has a `products` field that you are missing:

```
export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToCart: (state, action: PayloadAction<Product>) => {
      state.products.push(action.payload)
//          ~~~~~~~~
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQZQDbDJoA0cAChgJ54QYAmAgsjMBAHZwC+cAZlBCDgByAALo6AVwAeAKwDOAehgQIeANbAYQgLAAoPcDbYoPDEXL9JzRHGB0AXHDkwohgOZc9etFMixbRmgmZmhwAMIYsDgwWKEIenBwYJYSzHKOZCnMANoAunqcXrrI7M4BmsAYeNGxjhFRMdhwALyICUlZMOlweQVFPn7wJWxlyJEw+IShraiY2JNEABTxuolsGCBojkJjsELE7YYVVTXYB6tw4qlB3SuJifR0ACoQ9TCOi86xpGYs7BlUGj0Jh-NgAHkyECsMAAfABKFowtoXe5ORpoAB0yShqS6WIkcgAFotfqw2FjAbQ6HD2olChd6ZwafpdAoFHAQWSUOgsNA5HBIqE3Gg2EFYnReNA4JhkISUBg5KErkQoLwJGxmGS9Gzpb5oENSvAkI8Xm9SHQ0LNNkZSIYrSKYAAhSgMEAQdXwbgzcYLTGk0rePX+YZlY10Z6vcZcFryqIEIgY-0jfpB+AW0wSPBDH3xzHKoJAA)

Comment: yes, I realised this after stepping away for a few minutes. Thanks for confirming my assumption.